# Desktop shortcut and lock to launcher for phpstorm failed to launch program

Tags: unity, launcher, java

I have just installed phpstorm, phpstorm can be opened via command line but I can't open the program via launcher or desktop shortcut and nothing error shown.

**- My phpstorm.desktop code :**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Phpstorm
Exec=/home/mockie/softwares/PhpStorm-133.982/bin/phpstorm.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

**- For launcher shortcut, I created it through phpstorm menu**

> Tools > create desktop entry

Still no luck, the launcher failed to open the program.

**- This is how I run program via terminal :**

> /home/mockie/softwares/PhpStorm-133.982/bin/phpstorm.sh

**- Fyi: if I run it via command line, I got this deprecate message :**

> Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m;
>   support was removed in 8.0

*But phpstorm still can be opened successfully.*

**- I installed JRE on :**

> /home/mockie/softwares/jre1.8.0_20

Comment: The shortcut probably points to the wrong file. Could you include the shortcut file in the question?

Comment: sure @devGeek, I just edited my question :)

Comment: Does double clicking the icon even open terminal? And just to confirm, other desktop shortcuts still work right?

Comment: I haven't other shortcut except this. Terminal only open fleeting.

Comment: If I open via launcher it's only blinking and nothing happened. Is there any log to see this kind of error ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you ever got this to work, but the issue I'm almost certain was this:

The command you are executing should be:

```
/bin/bash /home/mockie/softwares/PhpStorm-133.982/bin/phpstorm.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing about permission. So, you can make it executable:

```
 cd /home/mockie/softwares/PhpStorm-133.982/bin
 chmod +x phpstorm.sh
```

Then, try create launcher again!